# You tube channels as Json

Tags: android, json, youtube-api

I am trying to create an android app ..for that i want to know how to retrieve the particular youtube channels videos as a json Data ..?I mean I dont want to search the videos i want to display only for particular channel videos..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HI,

Try this JSON Link
*http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**UserName**/uploads?&v=2&max-results=50&alt=jsonc*

here that content Object returns to my channel videos

Reference by

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Response_codes_uploading_videos